# Delete from a specific row to the last one

Tags: mysql

I have a table (cars) that has 26500 rows. Is it possible to delete from the row number 10001 through the end?

Comment: any way to define those rows?

Comment: needs more info to be answerable, and no need to SHOUT in titles please.

Comment: See LIMIT and OFFSET

Answer (score 1):

in **InnoDB Tables**

If you are deleting many rows from a large table, you may exceed the lock table size for an InnoDB table. To avoid this problem, or simply to minimize the time that the table remains locked, the following strategy (which does not use DELETE at all) might be helpful:

*Step 1: Select the rows not to be deleted  into an empty table that has the same structure as the original table:*

```sql
INSERT INTO `cars_copy`  SELECT * FROM `cars` LIMIT 10000 ;
```

*Step 2: Use RENAME TABLE to atomically move the original table out of the way and rename the copy to the original name:*

```sql
RENAME TABLE `cars` TO `cars_old`, `cars_copy` TO `cars` ;
```

*Step 3: Drop the original table:*

```sql
DROP TABLE `cars_old`;
```

No other sessions can access the tables involved while RENAME TABLE executes, so the rename operation is not subject to concurrency problems.

Answer (score 0):

When your Rows are labelled with an ID you can just do this:

```
DELETE FROM cars WHERE ID > 10000
```